# Reading Specific elements using XMLReader and adding values to a generic List

Tags: c#, generics, xmlreader

I am reading a huge XML file (250 MB) using XMLReader and add only specific elements to a generic List . I am unable to add values to the list correctly.I am getting null values in the List.I'll appreciate your help Below is the class I am using :

```
public class SomeInfo
    {
       public string Item1 { get; set; }

       public string Item2 { get; set; }

    }
```

My code to read XML is as below :

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file)
                )
            {
                List<SomeInfo> test = new List<SomeInfo>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var testObject = new SomeInfo();
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {

                        string name = reader.Name;
                        switch (name)
                        {
                            case "Item1":
                                reader.Read();
                                testObject.item1= reader.Value;
                                break;
                            case "Item2":
                                reader.Read();
                                testObject.item2= reader.Value;
                                break;
                        }
            test.Add(testObject);
                    }

                    }
```

Sample XML : This is huge xml file and I only need to read some elements and add to the list .In my code above, I am only reading Item1 and Item2 and do not care about Xitem,Bitem and Citem tags

```
<mainItem>
<Item>
      <Xitem>125</Xitem>
      <Item1>ab41gh80020gh140f6</Item1>
      <BItem>42ae3de3</BItem>
      <Item2>7549tt80384</Item2>
      <Citem>c7dggf66e4</Citem>
</Item>
<Item>
      <Xitem>865</Xitem>
      <Item1>ab41gh80020gh140f6</Item1>
      <BItem>42aejj3de3</BItem>
      <Item2>7549kljj80384</Item2>
      <Citem>c7df6kk6e4</Citem>
</Item>
<Item>
      <Xitem>895</Xitem>
      <Item1>ab41gjgjgh80020gh140f6</Item1>
      <BItem>42aehkh3de3</BItem>
      <Item2>754980384</Item2>
      <Citem>c7dfjj66e4</Citem>
</Item>
    </mainItem>
```

Comment: `reader.Read()` reads the next node from the stream. In your algorithm, for each node like `mainItem,XItem, Item1` you are creating an instance of `SomeInfo` class. So your list will have 19 elements instead of 3. I would suggest you to [try deserialize xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change as below

```
private List<SomeInfo> ProcessItems(XmlTextReader reader)
{
    List<SomeInfo> test = new List<SomeInfo>();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Name.Equals("Item"))
        {
            var testObject = new SomeInfo();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.Name.Equals("Item"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "Item1":
                            testObject.Item1 = reader.ReadString();
                            break;
                        case "Item2":
                            testObject.Item2 = reader.ReadString();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            test.Add(testObject);

        }
    }
    return test;

}
```

Usage :

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filepath));
List<SomeInfo> result = ProcessItems(reader);
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it creates two rows for each item in the List . If the xml contains 1 value of each , then by using the above Code , the list will contain 2 rows having item1=somevalue,item2=null and item1=null and item2=somevalue.Any ideas how to get around that ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having null values for `Item1` or `Item2` or is it that you see null values in the `test` list.

The culprit seems to be your code which is in a way that, every time the traversed node is an `XmlNodeType.Element`, you are adding the object to the list. Based on the your switch; if element is of type `Item1`, then `Item2` will be `null` in the test object and for `Item2` type, Item1 will be `null` always. Also, if your code have more element types, then objects which have both values as null would be inserted into your test object.

Comment: I agree that is the problem.Based on this , how and where should I add the data to the List ?